# GNU Radio simulation stuck

Tags: c++, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have attached a screenshot of my design here:

[image]

when I start simulating it stuck and only plot a few vectors of data.
I think it's becasue of variable time shift block, it's a hierarchy block, when I connect a constant source to i'ts float input the design works perfectly but when I connect output of short to float it does not work, 
I think it's becasue Argmax block produces one output for every vector but the variable time shift needs that output constantly.
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written an answer to this question that you also posted on the [discuss-gnuradio](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio) mailing list ([archive](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-07/msg00081.html)):

> Hi Mohammad,
>
> to try, you could just use the repeat block.
>
> Best regards, Marcus

I hope that solved your issue, since I haven't heard back from you :)

Comment: no problem at all :) best of luck with your application!